# asp.net mvc 5 how to set number into long value like 101-2esdf-1212

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

simple this is the model

```
public class Role
    {
        [Key]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; 
    }
```

Now for example I insert data for column name **RoleName** so the **RoleID** will be only integer like **(1)** if you see the default table of MVC 5 authentication model which id is like (**9704b331-a8fd-494e-a280-d53312689f17**) how can set or where to set to setup model for inserting long number with text instead of simple author incremented integer..

thanks in advance

Comment: Use [Guid.NewGuid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: let me do it...

Comment: but how to set in above model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild and Re-Create Controller and check...

```
 public class Role
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```